# How can I install Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 alongside each other?

Tags: re-installation, windows-xp

I've got Windows 7 with Wubi 11.10 installed. I would like to replace that with a proper 12.04 installation alongside a new Windows XP installation, but I'm not sure what the best path would be. I can't figure out how to install WinXP via USB -- my computer has no cd drive.

I'm not skilled enough to use Ubuntu all the time, and my iPhone requires me to run some Windows version for the damn iTunes software. I have all my data on the Windows partition but also lots of apps and settings in Ubuntu. I [back up](http://crashplan.com) the data on the Windows partition. I don't mind having to re-do the Ubuntu customizing.

**How can I install Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 alongside each other?**

Which one to install first? I think either one will "break" the boot of the other one, so afterward I'd have to repair the boot mechanism.

Comment: Is formatting an option?  Or you want to keep 7?

Comment: windows first then Ubuntu.

Comment: @Mitch: Formatting is an option, especially if I can manage to get back to WinXP instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most proper way is to install Windows XP first. Then install Ubuntu, which will find the XP install and deploy the proper GRUB boot.

As for installing Windows XP from USB, the easiest way to do this is to use [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/). There are about 3 other methods, but all of them are bound to fail.

Judging from your reputation and the way you formulated your question, this is all you needed to know and you're capable to do the rest yourself. If something is unclear, comment to ask for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all backup your data using a external hard drive or some services such as Google drive or dropbox.

Then  first of all,do a clean install of XP first using a bootable USB drive.Also make partitions on it so that you may have enough space for Ubuntu.

Next,You setup two drives for Ubuntu,one of /home and other for /.
The benefit of this would be that if ever you Ubuntu crashes or something  weird happens you will have all your data safe and all customization  in place and you won't have to reinstall  everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry too much about grub with XP, you will have to do an extra step if you install XP last - but it's not hard.

As you already have wubi - you could if you wished convert that to a 'real' install with a partition, then install XP afterwards.

All you would then need to do is reinstall grub.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstall_from_the_LiveCD

Answer (score 0):

I agree that if you have to install ubuntu and windows, I would recommend installing windows, partition the disk to leave free space, then install Ubuntu.

Two questions, why windows XP? It's outdated and not updated any longer. Why not keep Win 7? Use Win7 to reduce the windows partition, then install ubuntu using a usb stick which you can create through your current Ubuntu installation (Startup disk creator).

Probably you'll have to press a key combination or a function key (F2 for example) to get the boot menu and then choose USB stick.

On a different note, if you need windows only for itunes look here: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/itunes